# How to use Select2 with Inputmask

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-inputmask

I am trying to create a [Select2](https://select2.org/) box with [InputMask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) to insert IP addresses and add them as tags.

If I use any of the libraries on its own, it works like a charm but both together results in strange behavior.

When I type in numbers, the mask is not filled but rather it seems to expand.

I changed the type of the select2 `<input class=“select2-search__field“>` from `search` to `text`. The Inputmask library makes this necessary, but it should not cause errors because the types are [functionally identical.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/search)

I created a Fiddle to show the behavior: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ti_m/t4w4nk6L/)

HTML:

```
<select multiple id="sel1" style="width:100%"></select>
```

JS:

```
$("#sel1")
.select2({
   tags: true 
})
.on("select2:open", function () {
   $(".select2-search__field")
   .attr("type","text")
   .inputmask({alias: "ip", greedy: false});  
})
```

In my local example I changed the library to support `search` and the behavior is the same.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I have a solution but you need to use version <= 4.0.2. Is that acceptable ?

Comment: FYI I got this working with version 4.0.6-rc1 by using the jQuery Mask plugin over the Inputmask plugin:
https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

I know your question specified Inputmask, but if you're able to switch then it may be an option for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bad news for you if you **MUST** use version `4.0.5`.

Fixed in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yogeshgadge/m2376k6q/3/) by downgrading select2 to version `4.0.2`

The main thing is version <= `4.0.2`

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/js/select2.js

Tried `4.0.3` onwards up to `4.0.6-rc.1` but no luck.

Opened up [issue select2#5216](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/5216) with select2.

I did a slight change but that has nothing to do with the problem itself.

```js
$('.select2-search__field').attr('type', 'text');
$('.select2-search__field').attr('style', 'width: 10em;');
$('.select2-search__field')
.inputmask({
  alias: 'ip'
});
```